# Target dynamically created HTML element in function (for append event-- not click!) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, dynamically-generated

I want to target a dynamically created HTML table element inside another dynamically created table row, to append a table row in the sub-table before the last sub-table row. I do not want to attach a click event to this dynamically created element, which is the answer I seem to find everywhere. I want to target the specific sub-table (`.subTable`) in the specific table row (`this.closest("tr")`, this being the `.buttonHere` cell within the row I want to target the child table element) to append another table row before the last row (class `.subTableLastRow`).

So if I have:

```
$("#mainTable").on("click",".buttonHere", function () {
    $(this.closest("tr") > ".subTable" > ".subTableLastRow").before("<tr><td>another row</td><td>with two cells</td></tr>");
```

This is messy code and it obviously doesn't work, I'm just trying to explain what I'm trying to do. I hope this makes sense. Just a simple answer to how to target a dynamically created child element inside of another dynamically created parent element would be a lot of help, as clearly I am lost.

Comment: Just define your click handler on `#mainTable` and listen for `.dynamicChild` instead of `.buttonHere`. This way the event listener is "sitting" on the main table and receives all bubbled events from its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your jQuery selector was just formatted incorrectly.

```
$(".subTable .subTableLastRow", $(this).closest('tr')).before("<tr><td>another row</td><td>with two cells</td></tr>");
```

Additionally when trying to access jQuery methods on `this` you have to wrap it in a jQuery selector ie `$(this)`. This will make it a jQuery object and you can then utilize the jQuery methods.

Comment: Thanks for answering, though this doesn't work. Do you know what the problem may be?

Comment: Can you give an example of your html?

Comment: Just the hint I needed! This did work, I had the .subTableLastRow as an id, not a class. Fixed! Thank-you very much!